# Hide fields based on 2 date comparison

Tags: entities, datetime

I have a field (**field1**) where users can enter in a date that's in the future. Another field (**field2**) depends on field1 in a way that if todays date < **field1**, display **field2**. What's the best way to approach this? I cant find a way to do this using Rules and the Date module unless I'm not looking at the right place.

Also if todays date >= **field1**, dont display **field2** at all but instead display a 3rd field (**field3**).

Comment: Have you tried the https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields module?

Comment: @Collins Yes but doesnt have what Im looking for unless I'm looking in the wrong place..

Comment: When editing that content type, there should be a new tab called "manage dependencies", you can then say that if field1 = x, then show field 2